# how to make a collision with sprite nodes on Xcode swift

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

IM trying to  make a app but a collision of two skspriteNodes won't work. Please help.

Code:

```
// If statements
if CGRectIntersectsRect(heroRect, stoneRect){
    hittingTrigger()
}

func hittingTrigger() {
    heroB.removeFromParent()
    stoneGround.removeFromParent()
    yellowStripes.removeFromParent()
}



let heroB = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.grayColor(), size: CGSizeMake(32, 40))
        heroB.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2)
        self.addChild(heroB)
let stoneTrigger = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.grayColor(), size: CGSizeMake(32, 40))

heroB.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveRight))
      stoneTrigger.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))
 heroB.zPosition = 20
stoneTrigger.zPosition = 20
stoneTrigger.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2 + 200, self.size.height / 2)
```

The heroRect is the rect of his person. 
and the stoneRect is supposed to be a trigger and it won't work.

Comment: it runs perfectly but it won't work.

Comment: Please post the more code. Where is the if statement placed? In the update method? Are you using physics based collisions?

Comment: ok ZeMoon I'll do it now

Comment: let heroB = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.grayColor(), size: CGSizeMake(32, 40))
        heroB.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2)
        self.addChild(heroB)
 let stoneTrigger = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.grayColor(), size: CGSizeMake(32, 40))

Comment: Edit the question with the code, do not post it as a comment

Comment: heroB.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveRight))
 stoneTrigger.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))  heroB.zPosition = 20      stoneTrigger.zPosition = 20      stoneTrigger.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2 + 200, self.size.height / 2)

Comment: This is only the declaration of the sprites. Where is the CGRectIntersectsRect() method being called?

Comment: Huh? I dont understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your code to work as you want you need to:

1. Add **stoneTrigger** to an SKNode that belongs to the Scene tree as you are doing with heroB
2. Move the following code

   ```
   if CGRectIntersectsRect(heroRect, stoneRect){
       hittingTrigger()
   }
   ```

   inside the update method, infact you want to check for collisions every frame. (For a more elegant collision detection you should use the SpriteKit Physics Engine).
3. Use the appropriate SKSpriteNode initializer, if you don't want to use a texture you should use this

   ```
   SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.grayColor(), size: CGSizeMake(32, 40))
   ```

I prepared a simple GameScene that does what (I guess) you want:

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {

private let heroB = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.grayColor(), size: CGSizeMake(32, 40))
private let stoneTrigger = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.grayColor(), size: CGSizeMake(32, 40))

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    let moveRight = SKAction.moveByX(200, y: 0, duration: 10)
    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-200, y: 0, duration: 10)

    heroB.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2)
    heroB.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveRight))
    heroB.zPosition = 20
    self.addChild(heroB)

    stoneTrigger.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))
    stoneTrigger.zPosition = 20
    stoneTrigger.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2 + 200, self.size.height / 2)
    self.addChild(stoneTrigger)
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if CGRectIntersectsRect(heroB.frame, stoneTrigger.frame){
        hittingTrigger()
    }
}

private func hittingTrigger() {
    heroB.removeFromParent()
    println("Collision!!")
//      stoneGround.removeFromParent()
//      yellowStripes.removeFromParent()
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

Looking at my code there is something I don't like. The 2 instance properties **heroB** and **stoneTrigger** are retaining the related SKSpriteNode even when not necessary.
Infact even when heroB is removed from the GameScene, it still is allocated in memory. Given the simplicity of this example, it is not a big deal but for sure this is not a best practice. I revised my code in order to fix this. Here it is:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

private weak var heroB : SKSpriteNode?
private weak var stoneTrigger : SKSpriteNode?

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    let moveRight = SKAction.moveByX(200, y: 0, duration: 10)
    let moveLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-200, y: 0, duration: 10)

    let heroB = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.grayColor(), size: CGSizeMake(32, 40))
    heroB.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2)
    heroB.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveRight))
    heroB.zPosition = 20
    self.addChild(heroB)
    self.heroB = heroB

    let stoneTrigger = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.grayColor(), size: CGSizeMake(32, 40))
    stoneTrigger.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveLeft))
    stoneTrigger.zPosition = 20
    stoneTrigger.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2 + 200, self.size.height / 2)
    self.addChild(stoneTrigger)
    self.stoneTrigger = stoneTrigger
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    if let heroB = heroB {
        if let stoneTrigger = stoneTrigger {
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(heroB.frame, stoneTrigger.frame){
                hittingTrigger()
            }
        }
    }
}

private func hittingTrigger() {
    if let heroB = heroB {
        heroB.removeFromParent()
        println("Collision!!")
//      stoneGround.removeFromParent()
//      yellowStripes.removeFromParent()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thank you appzYourLife. it works on another project but not the one i want it to. I have loads of code. Shall I give you the rest?

Comment: One question: maybe the project you are talking about is not a SpriteKit project?

Comment: My project is in sprite kit i checked

Comment: Also i get thread 1 signal cigaret on my project. shall i give you the rest of my code to see whats happened?

Comment: I didnt mean cigaret I meant sigabrt and ok in a min